# Null Cipher -- Java

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to code the null cipher for a school assignment, and I have no idea what i'm doing wrong.

The cipher is supposed to obtain the char from the number given in the pattern class. If it's a "-1", end the program and return output. If the pattern returns "0", skip the word and move on to the next pattern value. Any other integer and the program should get the char from the word in that place.

So in the example below, the pattern is {1, 0, 0, 1, 5, -1}
And the text is: "Hello, is it me you're looking for".

The output should be : "Hmr"

But i'm getting an out of bounds error, and when I tweak it, it's not printing the correct chars.

The code is below, please help me.

EDIT: I change it so that the runtimeError would disappear, but now i'm getting the incorrect output: "e'[space]"

```
ArrayList<Character> text;
ArrayList<Character> output;
int outputLen;
ArrayList<Integer> pattern;

public Preform()
{
    text = new ArrayList<Character>();
    output = new ArrayList<Character>();
    pattern = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    {
        pattern.add(1);
        pattern.add(0);
        pattern.add(0);
        pattern.add(1);
        pattern.add(5);
        pattern.add(-1);
    }
}

public void updateLength()
{
    outputLen = output.size();
}

public void stringToChar(String input)
{
    for (int i = 0;i < input.length();i++)
    {
        String value = input.substring(i,i+1);
        text.add(value.charAt(0));
    }
}

public void printString ()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < output.size();i++)
    {
        System.out.println(output.get(i) + ", ");
    }
}

public ArrayList<Character> run()
{
    int nullValue = 0;
    int textVal = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < pattern.size(); i++)
    {
        nullValue = pattern.get(i);
        if (nullValue == -1)
        {
            return output;
        }
        else if (nullValue == 0)
        {
            textVal = nextWord(textVal);
        }
        else
        {
            textVal += nullValue;
            char temp = text.get(textVal);
            output.add(temp);
            textVal = nextWord(textVal);
        }
    }
    return output;
}

public int nextWord (int starting)
{
    // go to the next word
    int addVal = 0;
    do{
            starting++;
    } while(text.get(starting).equals(' '));
    addVal += starting;
    return addVal;
}

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Preform event = new Preform();
    event.stringToChar("Hello, is it me you're "
            + "looking for");
    event.run();
    event.printString();
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your exception: in run you have to check for `pattern.size()` not `test.size`. always look at the line where you get the exception.

a similar issue is in run where you compare text size, but actually mean pattern

Apart from that your code is way to complicated, i.e. instead of nextWord you can simply use "my string".split(" "); and you get an array of string containing each word. There are a few other issues, but that's for you to figure out (its an assignment after all)

Edit: your main logic issue is with the way you use nextWord in run. 
First you need to adapt nextowrd to actually do what you want (skip until the next space and then to the start of the next word):

```
public int nextWord (int starting)
{
    // go to the next word
    do{
            starting++;
    } while(!text.get(starting).equals(' '));
    // skip the space
    starting++;
    return starting;
}
```

and your logic in run where you get the correct char needs to be adapted too:

```
        else
        {
            char temp = text.get(textVal + nullValue - 1);
            output.add(temp);
            textVal = nextWord(textVal);
        }
```

Comment: Okay, I did it so that the exception would disappear, and I just edited the question along with the code. 

I understand that's more complicated than it needs to be, i'm just trying to code the assignment in java first before I have to implement it into MIPS. It's gonna be a pain in the butt, and I need to make it as simple as possible for it to work.